# Create an array consisting of triples of consecutive identical elements

Tags: c#

As I am learning programming using C#, I try to solve the following problem, for me it looks a bit difficult, please help:

Create an array consisting of triples of consecutive identical elements.

Below is what I came up with so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Array3NumbersApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 99;
            int[] buffer = new int[n];
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 2; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {

                if (i % 3 == 0)
                {
                    int k = rnd.Next(1, 30);
                    buffer[i] = k;
                    buffer[i-1] = k;
                    buffer[i-2] = k;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 2; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(buffer[i -2 ] + " " + buffer[i-1] + " " + buffer[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can suggest what am I doing wrong in that program?

Results I was getting, for example:

> 0 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 1 29 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 18 1 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 20 18 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 25 20 25 25 25 ...

It is not what is expected, right?

Please note, this is not a homework, but my attempts to come to grips with arrays... Thanks in advance for your comments! I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: For example 3 3 3 2 2 2 21 21 21 etc.

Comment: Try replace `i++` by `i+=3` and remove the line `if(i%3==0)`

Comment: If you're trying to learn how arrays work, I can think of a lot more effective ways to do it. What is the end goal here?

Comment: The goal is to learn from stackoverflow community. Please suggest other ways to do it. I am open minded.

Comment: @Kalten Thanks for your suggestion. I got the following result 26 26 26 26 26 16 26 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 25 16 25 ...

Comment: Ok, the array is being populated correctly now. You may want to look at how you are writing the results to the console.

Comment: Did you replace both i++ ?

Comment: I was doing the wrong printing

Comment: Console.Write(buffer[i -2 ] + " " + buffer[i-1] + " " + buffer[i] + " ");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize you may have not learned LINQ yet but for completeness here is a LINQ solution:

```
var list = Enumerable
    .Range(0,100)
    .Select( n => rnd.Next(1,30) )
    .SelectMany( n => new int[] { n, n, n } )
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are close to the solution.
I could help you out, but i think you might want to figure it out by yourself, so i'll just give you a **hint:**

You already know that you should populate the array in triples backwards like that:

```
int k = rnd.Next(1, 30);
buffer[i] = k;
buffer[i-1] = k;
buffer[i-2] = k;
```

Now I think you already got on which indices you want these statements to execute (2,5,8,...)

Now you have a nice arithmetic progression with "jumps" of 3 indices. Starting at i=2. Sounds like a small adjustment you have to do with the for loop :)

**EDIT:**

**MORE PRACTICE**

If you want to take this task a bit farther so you can practice more, then try to avoid situations that 'rnd' generates the same number in consecutive iterations (so you won't get 29 29 29 29 29 29 which isn't a triple but six consecutive identical)...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! That is exactly, what I need - a hint. I am willing to figure it all out.

Comment: If you want to take this task a bit farther so you can practice more, then try to avoid situations that 'rnd' generates the same number in consecutive iterations (so you won't get 29 29 29 29 29 29 which isn't a triple but six consecutive identical)...

Comment: @ShepenkovValeriy you're welcome. look at my edit if you want to be more accurate with task results :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop will miss element 0 because your initial value of i is not divisible by 3. i==3 is the first time you'll enter the assigning block for i-2, which means the first to initialise is element 1 (the second value).  Your second loop is plainly wrong. You are iterating over each element individually, but still doing writelines as if you are only doing every third element. This means that you output the elements multiple times even though the underlying array would be populated as expected. Just write out the current value in the second loop and in the first loop replace the i++ with i+=3 and drop the mod 3 condition as per Kalten's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, @Adam G!

Answer (score 1):

The only changes I would make are to remove the check for `i % 3 == 0` and just increment your loop  variable by 3. And then at the end, just output the array sequentially (don't need to do anything special there).

```
private static void Main()
{
    int n = 99;
    int[] buffer = new int[n];
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 2; i < buffer.Length; i += 3)
    {
        int k = rnd.Next(1, 30);
        buffer[i] = k;
        buffer[i - 1] = k;
        buffer[i - 2] = k;
    }

    foreach (int t in buffer)
    {
        Console.Write(t + " ");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I looked into both ways of doing it and understood my mistake! That is fantastic help, thank you All!

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps you understand ;-)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 3) // normally you should always start with i = 0
        {

            //if (i + 1 % 3 == 0) // no need for this anymore, we got i += 3
            //{
            //}
                int k = rnd.Next(1, 30);
                buffer[i] = k;
                buffer[i+1] = k;
                buffer[i+2] = k;

            Console.Write($"{k} {k} {k} ");
        }

        //for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 3) // skip the whole loop because it is/ was the same as the one above
        //{
        //}
```